# Alternative to deprecated RegExp.$n object properties

Tags: javascript, regex

I like using the `$n` properties of `RegExp` (`RegExp.$1`, `RegExp.$2` etc) to create regular expression one-liners.
Something like this:

```
var inputString = '[this is text that we must get]';
var resultText = /\[([^\]]+)\]/.test(inputString) ? RegExp.$1 : '';
console.log(resultText);
```

The MDN docs say that these properties are now deprecated. What is a better non-deprecated equivalent?

Comment: Shouldn't this be pretty [straight forward](http://jsfiddle.net/v6w7ewah/), noone ever really used the `$1-9` properties anyway, as they where always unreliable.

Comment: Wow, I've never seen anyone using these in the wild.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## .match / .exec

You can store the RegEx in a variable and use `.exec`:

```
var inputString = 'this is text that we must get';
var resultText = ( /\[([^\]]+)\]/.exec(inputString) || [] )[1] || "";
console.log(resultText);
```

How this works:

```
/\[([^\]]+)\]/.exec(inputString)
```

This will execute the RegEx on the string. It will return an array. To access `$1` we access the `1` element of the array. If it didn't match, it will return null instead of an array, if it returns null, then the `||` will make it return blank array `[]` so we don't get errors. The `||` is an OR so if the first side is a falsey value (the undefined of the exec) it will return the other side.

You can also use match:

```
var inputString = 'this is text that we must get';
var resultText = ( inputString.match(/\[([^\]]+)\]/) || [] )[1] || "";
console.log(resultText);
```

## .replace

You can use .replace also:

```
'[this is the text]'.replace(/^.*?\[([^\]]+)\].*?$/,'$1');
```

As you can see, I've added `^.*?` to the beginning of the RegEx, and `.*?$` to the end. Then we replace the whole string with `$1`, the string will be blank if `$1` isn't defined. If you want to change the `""` to:

```
/\[([^\]]+)\]/.test(inputString) ? RegExp.$1 : 'No Matches :(';
```

You can do:

```
'[this is the text]'.replace(/^.*?\[([^\]]+)\].*?$/, '$1' || 'No Matches :(');
```

---

If your string in multiline, add `^[\S\s]*?` to the beginning of the string instead and `[^\S\s]*?$` to the end

Comment: Thank you for answer but if pattern don't mach input string there is error TypeError: /\[([^\]]+)\]/.exec(...) is null

Comment: @GeorgiNaumov fixed :)

Comment: @GeorgiNaumov if that doesn't work for you I've added a `.replace` version

Comment: Why not just `String.prototype.match()`? `inputString.match(/\[([^\]]+)\]/)[1]`

Comment: :) I started the question to collect ideas.

Comment: @Jan if there are no matches, match will returns null which causes a TypeError

Comment: @vihan You mean exactly like `exec` does?

Comment: @Jan Yeah, I mentioned both match and exec in the header but it really doesn't matter

Comment: You might want to do `(… || [,""])[1]` instead of `(… || [])[1] || ""`